# All regex testers say pattern works but when in code it doesn't

Tags: c#, regex

I have tested this pattern in regex101 & regexpr and both show it working well, but I when I put it in my c# code, it allows incorrect strings.

Pattern as appears in code:

```
@"^-?((4[0-6])|(11[5-9]?|12[0-5]?))?(°[0-5][0-9]?)?([\s'])?([0-5][0-9]?)?([\s""\.])?"
```

should match a DMS latitude with degree between 40 and 46 or 115 and 125 like 43°34'45.54"

It should not allow the letter f and when i use an online tester, it works fine, but when I put it in my code, it says it is a match.

Here is my c# code:

```
        var patternList = new[]
        {
            @"^-?([14])$", // matches a 1 or 4
            @"^-?((4[0-6])|(11[5-9]?|12[0-5]?))([\s\.])([0-9]{1,10})$" // decimal -- matches 40-46 or 115-125 with period (.) then any number up to 10 places
            @"^-?((4[0-6])|(11[5-9]?|12[0-5]?))?(°[0-5][0-9]?)?([\s'])?([0-5][0-9]?)?([\s""\.])?", // matches full DMS with optional decimal on second - 43°34'45.54"

        };

        bool isMatch = false;

        foreach( var p in patternList )
        {
            isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(searchString, p);
        }

        if (!isMatch)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                "Please check your input.  Format does not match an accepted Lat/Long pattern, or the range is outside Oregon");
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post the link to your successful regex fiddle? [Mine](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e-%3f((4%5b0-6%5d)%7c(11%5b5-9%5d%3f%7c12%5b0-5%5d%3f))%3f(%c2%b0%5b0-5%5d%5b0-9%5d%3f)%3f(%5b%5cs%27%5d)%3f(%5b0-5%5d%5b0-9%5d%3f)%3f(%5b%5cs%22%5c.%5d)%3f&i=-+43%c2%b034%2745.54%22%0d%0a) says the string matches partially.

Comment: Wouldn't string.split and int.parse be easier to write and to maintain? Regex is not really suited to comparing numbers to ranges.

Comment: Are you sure the regex testers you are using follow the C# regex rules?  Yes different programming languages have different rules for regexes.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop looks buggy. After the loop `isMatch` is set to true if the last regex matches; otherwise to false. So the first two regexes are ignored. Probably not what you intend?

Comment: Move the `if (!isMatch)` block to the `foreach` right below `isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(searchString, p);`.

Comment: Can you give several examples of both valid and invalid input? Also, your last expression doesn't account for the end of input. Did you want it to end with a "$"? You could be getting a positive because the input at least STARTS with the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems I noticed. The first is that your last expression doesn't account for the end of the string. This is a corrected candidate expression:

```
  ^-?((4[0-6])|(11[5-9]?|12[0-5]?))?(°[0-5][0-9]?)?([\s'])?([0-5][0-9]?)?([\s""\.][0-9]+)?"$
```

...with this tweak at the end:

```
([\s""\.][0-9]+)?"$ # look for optional decimal places, plus ", and nothing more.
```

Second, your foreach loop should be adjusted thusly:

```
  foreach( var p in patternList )
      if(Regex.IsMatch(searchString, p))
      {
          isMatch = true;
          //exit the foreach loop
          break;
      }
```